# How to limit amount of extracted text with Tika server?

Tags: apache-tika, tika-server

In my scenario, i have some large PDF files and would like to limit the amount of text extracted and returned by tika server. I know it's possible using Java library directly. However, how can I do this when making HTTP requests to tika-server `/tika` endpoint?